# what is the difference b/w @Html.DropDownList and @Html.DropDownListFor in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

What is the difference between `@Html.DropDownList` and `@Html.DropDownListFor` in MVC3?

All I know is `@Html.DropDownList` is used to render a `dropdownList` with a `List` and `@Html.DropDownListFor` with a `Model`.

I am not sure if this is right or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DropDownList` is bound to arbitrary value you pass in and generates `input` named after parameter you pass in.

`DropDownListFor` is bound to property in your model (defined by expression passed in) and generates `input` named after that property according to defined model binder condition.

Comment: Worth noting that this is true for all Html Helpers such as TextBox and TextBoxFor etc as well. The only item that differs is EditorFor which is used to generate an appropriate chunk of Html given the UIHints and DataAnnotation attributes defined on the Model - there is no Editor equivalent because of this.